# Partitioning the data while reading from hive/hdfs based on column values in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, join, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I have 2 spark dataframes that I read from hive using the `sqlContext`. Lets call these dataframes as `df1` and `df2`. The data in both the dataframes is sorted on a `Column` called `PolicyNumber` at hive level. `PolicyNumber` also happens to be the primary key for both the dataframes. Below are the sample values for both the dataframes although in reality, both my dataframes are huge and spread across 5 executors as 5 partitions. ***For simplity sake, I will assume that each partition will have one record.***

`Sample df1
 PolicyNumber FirstName
 1            A
 2            B
 3            C
 4            D
 5            E`

`Sample df2
 PolicyNumber  PremiumAmount
 1             450
 2             890
 3             345 
 4             563 
 5             2341`

Now, I want to join `df1` and `df2` on `PolicyNumber` column. I can run the below piece of code and get my required output.

`df1.join(df2,df1.PolicyNumber=df2.PolicyNumber)`

Now, I want to avoid as much shuffle as possible to make this join efficient. So to avoid shuffle, while reading from hive, I want to partition `df1` based on values of `PolicyNumber` `Column` in such a way that the row with `PolicyNumber 1` will go to `Executor 1`, row with `PolicyNumber 2` will go to `Executor 2`, row with `PolicyNumber 3` will go to `Executor 3` and so on. And I want to partition `df2` in the exact same way I did for `df1` as well.

This way, `Executor 1` will now have the row from `df1` with `PolicyNumber=1` and also the row from `df2` with `PolicyNumber=1` as well.
Similarly, `Executor 2` will have the row from `df1` with `PolicyNumber=2` and also the row from `df2` with `PolicyNumber=2` ans so on.

This way, there will not be any shuffle required as now, the data is local to that executor.

My question is, is there a way to control the partitions in this granularity? And if yes, how do I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no direct control on the data which is floating into each executor, however, while you reading data into each dataframe, use the `CLUSTER BY` on join column which helps sorted data distributing into right executors.

```
ex: 
df1 = sqlContext.sql("select * from CLSUTER BY JOIN_COLUMN")
df2 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM TABLE2 CLSUTER BY JOIN_COLUMN")
```

hope it helps.